# SmtpClient.SendAsync code review

Tags: c#, .net, smtpclient, mailmessage

What is the proper way to dispose of `SmtpClient` and `MailMessage` while using `SendAsync`?

I have copied my code below.

```
{
...
var client = new SmtpClient {Host = _smtpServer};
client.SendCompleted += SendCompletedCallback;
var userState = mailMessage;
client.SendAsync(mailMessage, userState);
...
}

private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, 
    AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the unique identifier for this asynchronous operation.
    var mailMessage= (MailMessage)e.UserState;

    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        Log.Info(String.Format("[{0}] Send canceled.", mailMessage));
    }
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        Log.Error(String.Format("[{0}] {1}", mailMessage, e.Error));
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Info("Message sent.");
    }
    mailMessage.Dispose();
}
```

Disposing the `MailMessage` after the `client.SendAsync(...)` throws an exception. I need to dispose it in the Callback handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks correct.

Note that `MailMessage` does not override `ToString`, so your logs will simply say `[MailMessage] Send cancelled`.
You might want to use the `Subject` proeprty (or some other property) instead.

Comment: I was mislead because of this example from msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx where they dispose the mailMessage in the main function and not in the Callback.

Comment: @Lieven Cardoen, reason is, the example use a console and wait for the user input

Comment: Yes, but if you quickly press any key, you could get the same error as me, no? Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could help

```
   client.SendCompleted += (s, e) => { client.Dispose(); message.Dispose(); };
```

Comment: But using this way will sendcompleted event handler know exactly which client and message objects needs to be disposed? In case of using multiple async sends inside a loop.

I'm asking because in the first example he sends Message object through userState parameter.